# How to sort parent document by child documents lowest price in solr

Tags: solr, solr7

I am new in solr i want to sort parent document by child documents lowest price . Please see below mentioned sample data.

```
{
    "parentID": 1,
    "children": {
      "numFound": 2,
      "start": 0,
      "docs": [
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 1,
          "ID": "1",
          "price": 189.7
        },
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 1,
          "ID": "2",
          "price": 933.1
        }
      ]
    }   },   {
    "parentID": 2,
    "children": {
      "numFound": 2,
      "start": 0,
      "docs": [
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 2,
          "ID": "1",
          "price": 1180.0
        },
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 2,
          "ID": "2",
          "price": 238.0
        }
      ]
    }   },   {
    "parentID": 3,
    "children": {
      "numFound": 1,
      "start": 0,
      "docs": [
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 3,
          "ID": "1",
          "price": 1442.81,
        },
        {
            "type": "child",
            "parentID": 3,
            "ID": "2",
            "price": 42.81,
          }
      ]
    }   },   {
    "parentID": 4,
    "children": {
      "numFound": 1,
      "start": 0,
      "docs": [
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 4,
          "ID": "1",
          "price": 1140.8,
        }
      ]
    }   }
```

And i want to result below mentioned format

```
{
    "parentID": 3,
    "children": {
      "numFound": 1,
      "start": 0,
      "docs": [
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 3,
          "ID": "1",
          "price": 1442.81,
        },
        {
            "type": "child",
            "parentID": 3,
            "ID": "2",
            "price": 42.81,
          }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "parentID": 1,
    "children": {
      "numFound": 2,
      "start": 0,
      "docs": [
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 1,
          "ID": "1",
          "price": 189.7
        },
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 1,
          "ID": "2",
          "price": 933.1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "parentID": 2,
    "children": {
      "numFound": 2,
      "start": 0,
      "docs": [
        {
            "type": "child",
            "parentID": 2,
            "ID": "2",
            "price": 238.0
        },
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 2,
          "ID": "1",
          "price": 1180.0
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "parentID": 4,
    "children": {
      "numFound": 1,
      "start": 0,
      "docs": [
        {
          "type": "child",
          "parentID": 4,
          "ID": "1",
          "price": 1140.8,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I tried below mentioned link it's not worked for my issue.

[how to sort parent documents by child attributes in solr](https://blog.griddynamics.com/how-to-sort-parent-documents-by-child-attributes-in-solr/)

> sort={!parent which=type:parent score=max v=’+type:child +{!func}price’} desc